# Sending a mail when clicking on a link

Tags: android

This is the html element in my `Strings.xml` file.

```
<string name="five">
          <![CDATA[
         <HTML>
         <Body>
         <p>.................Some Text.......................

         <br><br>Feel free to contact us at<br> <font color="#add8e6">myemailid@gmail.com</font></p>
         </body>
         </HTML>
          ]]>
        </string>
```

Now, when the user clicks on `myemailid@gmail.com`, I want the yahoo mail or gmail or which ever mail application is present in the user's phone to open up and the `myemailid@gmail.com` to fill up the `TO :` field. Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the text you can use (assuming you have retrieved the string into a variable called text and are referenciing a TextView called textView)

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

---

When setting your layout you can also declare [android:autolink="email"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) on the Views holding the five string.

The description of autolink says "Controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links." i.e. the text within the View is parsed and any (in this case) email addresses in the text are converted to clickable links.

---

In the case of `android:autolink="email"` your other Html tags in the text wouldn't be processed and would be display as they are above (rather than as a processed HTML document).

Whereas `Html.fromHtml()` will handle the HTML tags and deal with correctly formated  tags.

Comment: I only want to make the email ID clickable. Not the whole textView.

Comment: Ah ha.. in each case this only makes the link clickable. In the case of Html.fromHtml your string needs to contain a valid a with href mailto. I think that the android:autolink will pick up any email addresses in the text.

Comment: Is it possible to change the default dark blue color of the link. It is hardly visible. Changing it in the text view will change the color of the whole html document. I also tried giving teh <font color>, but it is overridden and the dark blue color is displayed.

Comment: If you were using Html.fromHtml I guess you could add a style attribute to the <a href="mailto:blah" style="foo" />

Comment: Yeah I am using Html.fromHtml(). But like I said it doesn't pick up <font color> tag. Then will it pick up the style?

Comment: You need to use link selectors in the CSS style you apply http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: probably something like <a style="color: #800000" href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com" >Link Text</a>

Comment: Ah... try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColorLink

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Androids [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class.

As an example, if you do something like:

```
Linkify.addLinks(myTextView, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
```

any email address in the textview will be clickable and when clicked, an appropriate dialog will be shown to the user.

Ofcourse, this is assuming that your string is actually displayed inside a `TextView`

Comment: The whole string is in the text view.. I only want to linkify the email address.

Comment: The Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES parameter will ensure that only valid email addresses will be clickable and not any other text in the textview. For example, if the text is: "Hey! How are you? This is my new email: email@somedomain.com" then it will only create a link for the "email@somedomain.com" and nothing else. Besides, it will also, automatically ensure that apps which can handle an email address, are visible in the dialog shown to the user when the user clicks on the text